# A question about temperature change of a transducer

Tags: transducer

[This](http://www.rinstrum.com/us/en_downloads/12/38/Z6%20(b1010).pdf) load-cell has sensitivity Cn = 2mV/V. In the data sheet the only part about the temperature coefficient is:

[image]

How can I calculate the change in sensitivity for a 10°C temperature difference?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, dCn = Cn * 0.05% * dT / 10, where dCn is change in sensitivity, and dT is change in temperature in degrees Kelvin. Not entirely sure whether the temperature coefficient is positive or negative (the +/-0.0500 is confusing me there).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Now I have a similar problem with interpreting the amplifier: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339537/trouble-in-interpreting-and-calculating-temperature-effect-of-an-amplifier-modul  I would be glad to see your opinion.